# delphi Check whether function result value is used

Tags: function, delphi, return-value

My question is the same as [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693233/check-whether-function-result-value-is-used) except for the language. I am using Delphi.

*Following the link you'll see in Java this seems to be impossible, so I would assume this applies to Delphi as well, but I am not entirely sure*

### I want to know, whether a function can check, if the calling procedure/function is making use of the return value the function provides.

I've tried this, but it didn't work: (I guess if a solution exists it would behave similar to this)

```
  if Assigned(Result) then begin
    showmessage('return value is assigned');
  end else begin
    showmessage('return value is NOT assigned');
  end;
```

It may seem to be useless to check, but my function produces an encrypted file, for which the return value is beeing needed to decrypt this file, so it would be nice to notify the user instead of just producing an useless file and therefore I would like to check the usage of the return value.

### Possible workaround:

I've got an Idea, but either don't know whether this is possible nor how to do that: The function could scan the part of RAM, which is occupied by my application and check for the return value (String) to exist after the command `Result := 'something like F8975BE8AC0192#2983FE4A#B9DFE25'` has been fired. It is soooo unlikeley that the String exists twice, that this simple check would completely fit my purpose.
In general this may not work, because the Result could exist twice, but in my case this is somehow impossible.

So to do this workaround I expand my original question:
How can I search for a String in the part of RAM occupied by the application containing the function, which wants to check this?
As far as I know it would be much harder to check this for an external application, which is not needed here.

Comment: No, that is not possible. `Result` is a variable which can be accessed after the function returns and there's no way to determine whether it's consumed by the caller (even at compilation time as far as I know; Delphi doesn't have any kind of `_Check_return_` attribute like MSVC). But you can pass a `nil`able variable as parameter and check if that parameter reference is `Assigned` if you need this at runtime.

Comment: Seems more like a job for a static code analyser tool.

Comment: Where do you stop? You are going to check for every possible error? If the programmer gets thus wrong, the program doesn't work. That suffices.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes and no. I would like the function to handle two different use cases: If the return value is used, then well this is okay, as the key is beeing processed somewhere else, but if not the function should write this key directly to a file. The last one would be nice to use in a console app, where Windows Batch files could easily just tell the app to crypt and the app stores the keys at the right place, if nothing else is done with them. I know this could be done different, but I think this is somehow a valid solution.

Comment: - *"The function could scan the part of RAM, which is occupied by my application and check for the return value ..."* - A function returns when it does so. I mean when it returns, it is not executing any more. IOW, a function cannot return and at the same time not return and scan the RAM.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: A function returns when it does so, right, but the function (in Delphi) returns at the end of a function and not when the result is set, therefore the result can be set and afterwards the function can do stuff as well as for example scanning RAM.

Comment: The call site cannot use the result when it is set. It does so when the function returns.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: I know and that is not a problem as the calling method waits for the function to execute and then does or doesn't make use of the return value. It would just be nice for the function to know, whether the calling method does or doesn't use the value to decide, whether to save the key directly to file or not.
The call site just asks the function to do stuff and based on whether the call site is willing to use a returned value the function should be able to decide what to do. I just wanted to know if the function is able to know, whether the call site is willing to use the returns

Comment: EDIT: If i pass an additional variable, I'll do it the easy way and just pass a Bool to whether the Result is beeing used or not.

Comment: You can declare that parameter as `PChar` type (that's a pointer to string type). Or keep it as string and pass an empty value. Any of that won't gurantee, that the value is passed from a variable though. It can still be a constant value passed to a function call.

Comment: Probably I've been too concise. 1) The call site cannot use the result until the function returns. 2) The function cannot execute any code after it returns. Conclusion: A function cannot infer anything about what the call site does with what it returns. Not in Java, not in Delphi, not in anything. For this to happen a function has to travel in time.

Comment: @Victoria: I think I'll just pass a bool as mentioned above, but anyway I tried to pass nil as PChar and E2033 still occured. What am I missing?

@SertacAkyuz: 1) right, I never said it has to, so why do you mention that?
2) also right, but "returns" is when the call site is beeing made able to use the result and this is of course after setting the result, but not immediately. You can set the result by using `result:=''` then you can e.g. `showmessage` something and then the function ends and when the function ends it "returns" something. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong. However I can't see your point.

Comment: The point is I wrote, a function can set the return value, do stuff and then finish so the call site can do stuff as well and what I thought you wrote was  that between setting the return value and finishing the function can't do stuff, so I tried to disagree, so maybe we just talk past each other and there is no point anymore^^

Comment: Give it one more chance. Tell me when are you going to scan the RAM in the case you outlined.

Comment: I would check this before or after setting the return value, but before the function ends. So something like: [https://pastebin.com/HNUcgswf](https://pastebin.com/HNUcgswf)
But it would make sense to set the return value after the check, because if there is no making use of the value by the calling method returning something is unneccessary as it would not be used at all

Comment: *"if StringExistsInAssignedRAM('*see below') then do*" - This check will always fail because the call site does not have the return value yet, let alone it can make any use of it.

Comment: Of course the call site does not have the return value, but instead maybe the space reserved to store the return value. That's what I wanted to check and I dont know, whether Delphi reserves that memory before callinf a function or not. But I think you'll tell me it doesn't. I wouldn't expect Delphi to reserve the memory before calling something, but if it does my idea would work.

Comment: Why? How are you going to recognize that space since, *yet*, it doesn't contain anything? Besides why would reserving space guarantee usage. What if the caller discards the return due to a runtime check. That wouldn't effect reserving space, but would effect if the result is used or not.

Comment: If you fail to use the return value, your program won't work. Your tests will detect this. End of story.

Comment: @qGold: Your approach doesn't make sense, It is the responsbility of the **caller** to either use or discard the result. If different actions must be taken in your function, then the **caller** must signal this, somewhow (e.g. in a boolean parameter). It is not possible for your function to scan anything, The result is used when the function has stopped running, so it can't scan anything. That would be pretty slow and a totally wrong approach anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible in Delphi. And it's not a "language issue". But it's also ***not a problem***.

You're really thinking about this back-to-front. I'll try to explain the why; and hopefully you'll abandon this folly.

#### Summary

- Functions should do one thing only. The more things a function tries to do: the more difficult it is to implement correctly, and the more difficult it is for others to reuse.
- Any ***hack*** you may conceive can easily be bypassed. So you end up with more complexity and the same ***non-*** problem.
- It's not your responsibility to ensure that callers use your function correctly. That way lies madness and an ever-growing rabbit-warren.
- You should only implement your function according to a "contract" and it's the caller's responsibility to use it correctly. If caller doesn't use it correctly, caller has a bug until the calling code is fixed. *Simple as that.*

---

#### Do only one thing

When functions do more than one thing, it becomes impossible (without careful refactoring) to use one feature and not the other. The function is more difficult to test because: more things change during the call, more setup is required, more things should be checked, there are likely more permutations that need to be considered.

The scenario in the Javascript question is even worse because the 2 things have a fundamental difference:

- The function-style version can guarantee not to change state.
- Whereas the other style is intended to modify state.

This is a concept of mutability vs immutability. And it's extremely beneficial to know when ***immutability*** is guaranteed. Bundling both into a single function means you no longer have *immutable* version.

#### Hacking a "solution" is pointless

Let's suppose you find some hack to interrogate the call-stack *outside* the function itself in order to confirm the caller stores the function result to a variable for later use.

Let's also put aside concerns of different OS, CPU architecture, compiler optimisations etc.

Nothing prevents the caller doing the following:

```
S := HybridFunction(...);
if (S <> '') then S := '';
```

Yes caller stored the variable, but quite obviously didn't use it. But caller doesn't even have to be so blatant about it. Storing the variable in a class field but never referencing it again has the same effect.

#### Do not double-check your callers - it is NOT your responsibility

You have enough to worry about ensuring your code behaves correctly without having to worry about what your callers do. If you try to compensate for callers then:

- If caller is correct, your special code is pointless.
- If caller is wrong, you can't "fix" anything. You cannot know what every possible caller should do.

The effort is better spent working on the caller code and ensuring it ***is correct***!

Also, if you worry about your callers; what about your caller's callers? Or your caller's caller's callers? ... *It never ends.*

#### Implement to a contract and be done

You can force your caller to receive a result by using an **out** parameter. But that still doesn't prevent the caller from ***not using*** the **out** value after the call. So you'd sacrifice clean function-style calling convention for zero benefit.

I assume you have a function along the following lines:

```
function EncryptFile(): TKey; { returns the decryption key }
```

There's already a problem here because your function is obviously doing 2 things. Split it into 2 functions and your caller will also be easier to write.

```
function GetKey(): TKey;
procedure EncryptFile(AKey: TKey);
```

Then your ***caller can validate*** before trying to Encrypt:

```
LKey := GetKey();
if Assigned(LKey) then 
  EncryptFile(LKey)
else { report the error as you choose }
```

*And this is why I say you're going about this back-to-front*.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question might stem from either the desire to implement something absolutely bullet-proof, or a design choice that makes things harder than they are.

### Bullet proof implementation

If you have done a good job as a developer, function naming and signature will indicate the intended use to a caller. Whether he understands that and uses it correctly in the end, is likely out of your control, as comments have indicated: where do you stop? There might always be a way to defeat your implementation.

**Can and should anything be done?**

But thinking about the technical aspect of your question and the inability to check if something is done with a function result - as the functions code is already exited - my idea would have been to make the result itself 'smarter'.

You mentioned your encryption key is a string you would call 'unique'. So it could be possible to use Delphi's string reference counting - at least for strings other than `WideString` - to make sure it is still referenced somewhere. Coupled with an `IInterfacedObject` that is also reference counted, the `TInterfaceObject` could check if it outlives the monitored string.

**Interface**

```
  IRefCheck = interface
  ['{E6A54A33-E4DB-4486-935A-00549E6793AC}']
    function Value: string;
  end;
```

**Implemented by a `TInterfacedObject`**

```
  TRefCheck = class(TInterfacedObject, IRefCheck)
  strict private
    FString: string;
  public
    constructor Create(const S: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Value: string;
  end;
```

**Implemented like**

```
constructor TRefCheck.Create(const S: string);
begin
  FString := S;
end;

destructor TRefCheck.Destroy;
begin
  Assert(StringRefCount(FString) > 1, 'Reference check failed for ' + FString);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TRefCheck.Value: string;
begin
  Result := FString;
end;
```

So whenever `TRefCheck` is destroyed and holds the only reference to its string, the `Assert` will fail. I opted for the interface as result because when it was a string, the caller didn't need to control the life-time of the result and doesn't need now. Your function will now look similar to this:

```
function GetEncryptedFileKey(Key: string): IRefCheck;
begin
  Result := TRefCheck.Create(Key);
end;
```

And is used like this:

```
procedure Test;
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := GetEncryptedFileKey('Test Value 1').Value;
  GetEncryptedFileKey('Test Value 2');
end;
```

A small test program calling `Test` will fail with

> EAssertionFailed: Reference check failed for Test Value 2

As this requires the knowledge of the `IRefCheck` interface for the caller to access the `Value` and implicit operators are not available for classes (or interfaces) I tried it with an record, so it can be used like your string function before:

```
  TRefCheckRec = record
  private
    RefCheck: IRefCheck;
    function AsString: string;
  public
    class operator Implicit(Value: TRefCheckRec): string;
    class function CreateNew(S: string): TRefCheckRec; static;
  end;

function TRefCheckRec.AsString: string;
begin
  RefCheck.Value;
end;

class function TRefCheckRec.CreateNew(S: string): TRefCheckRec;
begin
  Result.RefCheck := TRefCheck.Create(S);
end;

class operator TRefCheckRec.Implicit(Value: TRefCheckRec): string;
begin
  Result := Value.AsString;
end;
```

Your function and the test code then look like this:

```
function GetEncryptedFileKey(Key: string): TRefCheckRec;
begin
  Result := TRefCheckRec.CreateNew(Key);
end;
procedure Test2;
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := GetEncryptedFileKey('Test Value Record');
  GetEncryptedFileKey('Test Value Record 2');
end;
```

**At the end** even with all this, defeating is as easy as never really 'using' `S`, in fact the test code does exactly that. All fluff and **no advantage** over

```
function GetEncryptedFileKey: string;
```

or

```
procedure EncryptFile(var EncryptionKey: string);
```

### Design choice

Reading your comments and the question what I believe I would have done is encapsulate your logic into a class, and let your function return an instance of it.

```
  TEncryptedFile = class
  private
    FEncryptionKey: string;
    FKeyPersisted: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function GetEncryptionKey: string;
    procedure SaveEncryptionKeyToFile;
  end;

constructor TEncryptedFile.Create;
begin
  FKeyPersisted := False;
  FEncryptionKey := ...
end;

destructor TEncryptedFile.Destroy;
begin
  if not FKeyPersisted then
    SaveEncryptionKeyToFile;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TEncryptedFile.GetEncryptionKey: string;
begin
  Result := FEncryptionKey;
  FKeyPersisted := True;
end;

procedure TEncryptedFile.SaveEncryptionKeyToFile;
begin
  FKeyPersisted := True;
  // Save to file
  ...
end;
```

Your function now returns an instance of it, caller is responsible for clean-up, as indicated by function name.

```
  function CreateEncryptedFile: TEncryptedFile;
  begin
    Result := TEncryptedFile.Create;
  end;
```

Whether he decides to access your key directly or save it to a file is up to him. If he cleans up the instance and none of both is done already, the key is automatically saved.

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you are asking is whether you can return two pieces of data from a function, the encrypted string and the decryption key.
You can either declare a class with the two items and return an instance of that or you can pass them both back as part of the parameter interface.

```
procedure cruncher(incoming:string;var encrypted:string;var decryptkey:string)
```

As a matter of personal style, I would be against passing back half the answer through a function result.

Comment: The encrypted thing is a file not a string, which the function saves automatically. The String I want to pass contains the decryptkey, which should normally be used somehow and to ensure this I wanted to check, whether it is used to otherwise save it to file, if the key is not used. 
There is no need to make use of the key for the calling method as long as the function saves the key if it is not used.